# Has css backface property broke in latest Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation

I had a site using a flip using css transforms and backface set to hidden. Which are now not working and i have just updated my chrome.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hmktf

Comment: Works in the latest Chrome for me (Mac).

Comment: should have mentioned my version :  33.0.1750.152 (mac/mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

They say this bug appears from time to time, or mabye always exists for certain versions:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39044

[Backface visibility broken in Chrome (certain platforms/versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355564/backface-visibility-broken-in-chrome-certain-platforms-versions)

One guy at the first link says there's a workaround:

> I am seeing *some* of the content through the back face. Giving the
>   element opacity: 0.99 fixes the problem.

But I don't know if it will work or not. I don't seem to have the problem in my Chrome (Win 8, version 33.0.1750.154 m)