# Backface still visible even it is set to "hidden"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a [simple "flip card"](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/yVut2/) in CSS3, and when a user hovers over the card, it would flip downward and show the other side. `backface-visibility` is set to `hidden` so the back face will not be shown. However, when I try flipping the card, the backside is still showing up.

So I have taken a look in the [working examples](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html) I found, and interestingly I have almost the same thing as his, and his does work but not mine. <sub><sup>(How is that even possible?!)</sup></sub> Following [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506148/283863) also does not work <sub><sup>(because I have already set everything `backface-visibility` to `hidden`)</sup></sub>.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
$(".wrapper").hover(function () {
    $(".flip").stop().transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateX: '-180deg'
    }).toggleClass("down");
}, function () {
    $(".flip").stop().transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateX: '0deg'
    }).toggleClass("down");
});
```

Any idea on why this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small addition does the trick:

```
.flip {
  ...
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Without or with another prefix for non-webkit browsers, depending on their support.

Comment: The only non-WebKit browser supporting `transform-style` is Firefox, which supports it without a prefix.

Comment: You are partially right. Support without a prefix is only offered in recent versions of Firefox. `transform-style` is also supported by IE10, but not the value `preserve-3d`.