# How can I hide the backface of a block element rotated with transform: rotateX()?

Tags: css

Per this example: http://jsbin.com/zuyena/4/edit, I've got two elements, one after the other inside a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">... text ...</div>
  <div class="box box2">... text ...</div>
</div>
```

With the help of CSS transitions/animations, I'd like to animate the `box2` to appear as though it's flapping down from underneath of `box1`. Omitting the actual transition, I'm pretty close with:

```
.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.box2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  /* Doesn't this hide the back face? */
}
```

However, as you can see in this example, the back face of `box2` is visible behind `box1`, despite `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`. How can I prevent this?

P.S. I am only using `-webkit` prefixes to keep the example simple.

Comment: Replace -webkit-backface-visibility with display: none; ?

Comment: Please check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455502/webkit-backface-visibility-not-working) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `perspective`!
until `-90deg` it doesn't have any back-face to hiding!
try to set `-91deg`, and see your back-face will hiding.

```
.box2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-91deg); /*now it will work*/
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You speak the truth. Thanks for pointing this out. So the question, then, becomes this: how can I get the desired effect? I want to keep the perspective, but I also do want the back face to be invisible when it's behind the top box. Any ideas? Skew?

Comment: @dimadima: How about `Opacity: 0;`?

Comment: @Harry: for some reason I tried `opacity: 1` on the top box, but not `opacity: 0` on the bottom box. That would be a good hack, for sure. Thanks. I am wondering, though, how to do this "correctly"

Comment: @Harry here's an updated JSBin w/ that hack: http://jsbin.com/zuyena/7/edit. Looks ok. Still want to know how to do this right.

Comment: @Harry, yes, totally. You know, I think that's actually good enough of a hack for me! It would be nice to know the proper way, and please post if you find out, but I'm totally cool w/ this approach. Thank you!!

Comment: @Harry: you may be interested in my answer to this question, too. Figured out what was going on after my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24854509/. The section on perspective at http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/css-transforms was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`backface-visibility` only kicks in when the transformation angle on an element is explicitly less than `90deg`s.

However, if an element's perspective is derived from its parent via the `perspective` and `perspective-origin` properties, the back face might still be showing, even if the transformation angles specified on that element are greater than `-90deg`s. There is probably no way around this, because that is the nature or deriving perspective from a parent element: the specified degrees of transformation on the child element are not solely responsible for the net transformation.

If you want an element's net transformed angles to be exactly per your specified transformation, then you have to set the perspective directly on that element with `transform: perspective($deg)`.

Check out [Is it possible to set perspective-origin on elements that are transformed with transform: perspective()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24854509/) for more information.