# Is it possible to set perspective-origin on elements that are transformed with transform: perspective()?

Tags: css

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to set the vanishing point (`perspective-origin`) for an element that is given perspective directly via `transform: perspective()`, as opposed to inheriting it from a parent via `perspective:`?

You can see an example at http://jsbin.com/fevik/2/edit. In the second set of elements, I would like each element to have its own vanishing point that I can specify.

**Discussion:**

It's easy to set the vanishing point (`perspective-origin`) for elements that are 3D-positioned by their parent. Supposing I have two `div`s inside a container:

```
<div id="cont1" class="cont">
    <div id="a" class="box"></div>
    <div id="b" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Then, I can give them perspective and a common vanishing point with:

```
#cont1 {
    -webkit-perspective: 400;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 100% 100%;
}

#cont1 .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
}
```

You can see the result in the first set of transformed elements at http://jsbin.com/fevik/2/edit.

Is it possible, however, to set the `perspective-origin` on elements that are transformed with `perspective-transform`, like in the second example:

```
<div id="cont2" class="cont">
    <div id="c" class="box"></div>
    <div id="d" class="box"></div>
</div>


#cont2 .box {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400) rotateX(-35deg);
}
```

I can't find a way. No matter what, the elements in the second example have their vanishing point directly in the middle behind them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that with perspective set via `transition`, `transition-origin` plays the role of `perspective-origin`.