# Backface Visibility not working on children

Tags: css, css-transforms

This solutions ([Webkit backface visibility not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455502/webkit-backface-visibility-not-working)) didn't work, as I'd like to have other transformed objects inside container that should show the backface.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
}
.container img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input:checked + .container {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://jsequeiros.com/sites/default/files/imagen-cachorro-comprimir.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

The backface of that cat shouldn't be visible. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: The title says it: when the image turns, both faces are visible, but the backface should be invisible

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally discovered how to solve this!
The problem was the the 3d was not affecting the image. Just by adding the property:   `transform-style: preserve-3d;` includes the image as part of the "3d world". Before, the backface property wasn't working, because it really wasn't 3d! It was like a texture painted on the parent's surface. Now it is a 3d entity with all its components and it can be transformed in 3d without collapsing to the surface of the parent.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.container img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input:checked + .container {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://jsequeiros.com/sites/default/files/imagen-cachorro-comprimir.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware of the "-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;" for Chrome, Safari & Opera. I forgot this and started to do all sorts of manipulation until I found that this answer and understood I had forgotten the -webkit-version since I was testing in Safari. Thanks for saving me a lot of time!!! :D

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
setting `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the elem you're transforming solve the issue

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
}
.container{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}
input:checked + .container {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://todofondosdeamor.com/wp-content/uploads/images/48/gatitos-1__400x300.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that container can't have backface-visibility hidden. If it could, the answer would be just transforming it. That is why I said that the solution I linked to isn't usefull in this case.

Comment: you're rotating .container

Comment: yeah, but I don't want to hide every objects backface inside the container, only that image